# Display content on top of the cast home screen

Tags: google-cast, google-home, google-cast-sdk

I was wondering if it is possible to create and display content with the cast sdk but on top of the standard cast home screen. For example, I would like to display a popup for a second but continue to display the nice backgrounds exposed by Chromecast. I haven't seen anything on the doc but recently, google has shown an example where you can ask the meteo to your google home and the result is displayed in foreground of the cast home screen.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your use case is not supported by the Google Cast SDK.